# Let Scala infer type for me according to argument length

Tags: scala, types, type-inference

Function or Tuple etc. has capacity that Scala can inference their type according to their argument length(arity).
e.g. `(1,2) is of type Tuple2`

Can I make such thing using Scala?

I provide my toy case :

```
implicit class EnrichedWithToTuple[A](elements: Seq[A]) {
  def toTuple2 = elements match {case Seq(a, b) => (a, b) }
  def toTuple3 = elements match {case Seq(a, b, c) => (a, b, c) }
  def toTuple = (*elements) // what I want is Scala infer the Tuple'N' for me by arg length.
}

val tuple = List(1, 2, 3).toTuple
```

Comment: I don't think that would work at all. You basically want `toTuple` to have different return types. Your could put several `match` statements inside `toTuple` (rather than separate methods), but then you would have to return `Any`.

Comment: Similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149179/how-can-i-use-shapeless-to-create-a-function-abstracting-over-arity

Comment: The number of arguments to a method is known at compile-time, but the length of an arbitrary `Seq` is not. You could use a macro (in which case you'll have to give compile-time failures for many `Seq` values) or something like Shapeless's `Sized`, but as written this isn't possible.

Comment: thanks, as @TravisBrown said, my question is somewhat wrong that List length is not known in advance.

Comment: @WeiChingLin I wouldn't say the question is "wrong"—it's definitely a reasonable thing to want, and if you're willing to use macros or Shapeless you can get much of the way there.