# How to expand a function type to a function with more arguments

Tags: scala

Given a function `f: Function[A,B]`, is there a generic way to produce a function of type `Function2[A, C, B]` that ignores the second argument? And more generically, expand any function type to take any number of arguments that are ignored?

Comment: Well you can do `(a, _) => f(a)` but as a method or something that quickly adapts to any arguments no that I know. Maybe **Shapeless** has something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why you want something like this but for number of arguments fixed to 2, you can do something basic like

```
def expandF[A, B, C](f: A =>B) : Function2[A, C, B] = 
  (a: A, c: C) => f(a)
```

In this case the following call to `a` will still return 10

```
def f1(a: Int) = {
  a + 5
}

val a = expandF(f1)

a(5, "Hello")
```

The generic version is more difficult for a few reason

1. The number of function arguments in Scala 2 is upper bounded by 22 so it will never be truly generic ([this limit was dropped in Scala 3](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/dropped-features/limit22.html#:%7E:text=The%20limits%20of%2022%20for,to%20a%20new%20trait%20scala.) )
2. Scala's static strict type system will start to get annoyed by this in the truest generic scenario. You can use `_*` which allows you to pass a collection of arguments but given the collections are homogenous, you will be limited to a single type across the arguments.

This is where generic programming using [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) would come into play. You can abstract over the arity using shapeless, see the linked question.

[How can I use Shapeless to create a function abstracting over arity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149179/how-can-i-use-shapeless-to-create-a-function-abstracting-over-arity)

And then define an `expand` function like above that constructs one of these variable arity functions from a unary function.

Without knowing exactly what purpose this serves and the use cases, it is very hard to come up with a one size fits all approach. Depending on how you want this transformation applied, you might even need to write a macro. This is all I can provide with the information at hand